# How Are New Routers Added To The Internet?

Tags: networking, router

How are new routers added to the internet? For example, if I have a server with a public address, is it possible to become a router on the internet? If I can, how?

(edit) Becoming a router on the internet means that the server now routes and receives the routing table like any other router on the internet. I don't mean the wireless routers at home but the routers that are in charge of getting packets around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You become a router on the internet if your closest connected peer decides to route more than a single address to your host, and you have somewhere to route the addresses to. Like another network. All networks of public internet addresses are called the Internet.

Internet addresses are administrated by a few entities (Regional Internet Registries, called RIR's for short) in the world: RIPE (Europe), ARIN (North-America), Lanic (South and Middle-America), AfriNic (Africa) and ApNic (Asia and Pacific). When you register a block of IP addresses you will need a provider to announce those addresses to other networks.

If you want to announce those addresses yourself you will need to be an autonomous network within the Internet. This starts with an a number which are also administered by RIR's: the Autonomous System (AS) number. With this AS number you can connect to other providers (peers) to route traffic from your network to other networks.

Routing traffic to other network is costly. It requires equipment and a lot of links between countries and their data-centers (also called point-of-presence, PoP's). Some transit providers (these are a kind of providers for providers) will provide a network to connect you to other providers. Transit providers will charge you for the traffic.

You can also connect directly to other providers given you will make a network connection to their PoP or join an Internet Exchange where multiple providers share one common network to exchange traffic.

All these connections between providers (transit, on exchanges or private peering) will use BGP to exchange optimal routes between providers. For example: a provider that provides access to a lot of customers will be more happy to exchange high bandwidth content over a private peering connection or public exchange than a costly transit provider. Configuring BGP will make this happen.

There is a whole world of options between becoming an full blown ISP just hosting a single server, delegating some of the tasks to another ISP. For example, you can get your own IP addresses and connect to multiple ISP's asking them to announce your network on their infrastructure and providing you multiple uplinks.

But let me emphasize on the terminology again: the 'Internet' is just the name of all networks of all transit providers, access providers, hosting providers and other content providers combined. There is no One-Internet where Microsoft, Google or your local cable provider connect to. When they connect to their peers (all other providers) they 'become' the Internet.

And to get to your root question: a new router on the internet is just someone, who is an ISP or is connected to an ISP who connects a router to its network which is using a routing table (BGP or static) to route traffic from one network to another. So in this view, even a home router, or a small office router is a part of the Internet. There are 'core' routers at ISP's which handle more traffic, or are just purposed to route traffic to other peered ISP's. But to me those are just as good routers of the Internet. Also, there is usually not one core router in the network of an ISP, its setup redundantly and will have delegated duties (connecting to specific peers in specific data-centers).

An analogy would be a rail network. How do you become transfer station? Just build one, and make trains stop there and connect people rails to other statios. There is some planning involved with other railway companies who own other stations you want to connect to, but hey: if you want to build a railway network you need to connect somewhere :)

Comment: I meant how to be a router on the one network: the internet. How do I do that?

Comment: I have rewritten my answer. I think you have a misunderstanding about the internet. There is no 'one' network. The Internet is the name of the network of all parties connected. The history lies there as well: ARPA net (the Internet name when in research by the US DoD and universities) was just a bunch of universities and research centers who connected their networks to each other and coordinated their IP address usage (that was a bit later when IP addressing was used). Hope this will give a bit more understanding. Have fun learning!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as long as:

**1. the server has software which can speak BGP**

BGP4 is the primary inter-network routing protocol used on the Internet, so using it is unavoidable. There are BGP implementations for Linux and BSDs.

**2. it's connected to an ISP which agrees to accept your BGP connection**

Usually this means a direct connection to your server's hosting company – even some VPS hosts offer BGP as an additional service (someone made [a large table](http://bgp.services/)). I think it is much more common with dedicated hosting and colocation services, but I've never used those so far.

It is *possible* to do the same across a tunnel/VPN (e.g. NetAssist and Tunnelbroker/HE.net offer BGP tunnels for IPv6, in addition to the usual static kind).

**3. you have an "autonomous system number"**

To announce your own routes to the whole Internet, you'll usually need to use a "global" AS number assigned by a [RIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) such as RIPE or APNIC.

On the other hand, some ISPs let you use a "private" ASN if you only want to receive routes, or if the ISP agrees to use its own ASN for your addresses.

**4. you're not expecting to grab someone else's packets**

Generally you'll only be able to announce IP address prefixes that *you own* – your ISP is *supposed to* limit exactly what routes you announce. In other words, having BGP connections doesn't automatically mean other people's data will start flowing through your router. (Although this does occur at times, either by accident or malice.)

Comment: I meant how to be a router on the one network: the internet. Also, if I have a server with a public address, one that hosts http for example, could I claim to have access to an IP address that is not under my router? How does the network resolve such disputes? At the same time, can I host a router without a ISP?

Comment: The internet is by design a network-of-networks. (Hence its name.) While the internet is a network, each "autonomous system" is a network as well.

Comment: "Claiming access" to other IP addresses is exactly what BGP route advertisement _does_. Each BGP router has an address and advertises that it'll be routing traffic for more addresses. The only difference is whether you're asking about legitimate claims or not. (Like I mentioned, your ISP is supposed to limit these announcements...)

Comment: You can host a BGP router without an ISP, but that kinda means it wouldn't have access to the entire internet. (Of course, you can still have direct peerings with individual companies, such as Google.) For the purposes of this thread, your server hosting company _is_ an ISP, as it provides internet access to the server itself.

Comment: But the IP addresses we are using is the internet's IP addresses, right? For example I want to access Bing at 202.89.233.100, it is the IP address from the internet and not any other network of the "network of networks", right? How do I claim access to the an IP address from the internet, and how do I prove that the claim is legitimate without showing up in person to my ISP and telling them that?

Comment: I'd say it's simultaneously an Internet address and Microsoft network address, as it belongs to a block that was given to Microsoft (and of course Microsoft use it on a network that's part of Internet). For another example, 2a06:e881:108:2::1 is an Internet address _and_ my home network address. Same for your own addresses, the ISP will check IRR database entries (i.e. WHOIS entries for that IP address, and WHOIS entries for the AS number) to make sure the RIR has granted you the address block. In the ARIN region they might ask for a "letter of authorization".